# Can I use newly created variables in the following expressions in `polars`?

Tags: python-polars

In `R` (and in particular in `dplyr::mutate()`), I'm used to use newly created variables in the following expressions, like so:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

head(iris) |> 
  mutate(
    sp1 = Sepal.Length + 1,
    sp2 = sp1 + 1
  )
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species sp1 sp2
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 6.1 7.1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.9 6.9
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 5.7 6.7
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 5.6 6.6
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 6.0 7.0
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 6.4 7.4
```

I'm now trying to learn `polars` and it seems I can't reproduce this behaviour (I'm using the Python version here to stick to the source as close as possible since the `R` version is not very complete yet):

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5]})

mod = df.with_columns(
    (pl.col("nrs") + 1).alias("nrs+1"),
    (pl.col("nrs+1") + 1).alias("nrs+2")
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<PATH>", line 6, in <module>
    mod = df.with_columns(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PATH>", line 7260, in with_columns
    .collect(no_optimization=True)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<PATH>", line 1501, in collect     
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
exceptions.ColumnNotFoundError: nrs+1
```

`pip show polars`:

```
Name: polars
Version: 0.18.0
```

Is this feature unavailable with `polars` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparison to `dplyr:mutate`, polars will run every expression in a single `with_columns` in parallel while `mutate` does everything sequentially. Since dplyr is doing each column sequentially, when it gets to your second column definition, the first one has already been created so it will just work. Whereas with polars, it sends each column/expression to its own thread/process (I'm not sure which) at the same time so the second one doesn't know anything about the first. This is why with polars, you have to execute it as two `with_columns`. By example, in `dplyr`, doing:

```
head(iris) |> 
mutate(
    sp1 = Sepal.Length + 1,
    sp2 = sp1 + 1
)
```

is the same as doing

```
head(iris) |> 
mutate(
    sp1 = Sepal.Length + 1
) |> 
mutate(
    sp2 = sp1 + 1
)
```

From a quantity of code perspective, the polars way may be more cumbersome and with smaller data that may be the most important consideration. You can monkey patch in a mutate function that will give you the `dplyr` method of doing everything sequentially such that the syntax you're used to remains, although you're giving up parallelism in the process.

The monkey patch is this:

```
def mutate(self, *args, **kwargs):
    lazydf=self.lazy()
    for value in args:
        lazydf=lazydf.with_columns(value)
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        lazydf=lazydf.with_columns(**{key:value})
    return lazydf.collect()
pl.DataFrame.mutate=mutate
del mutate
```

That allows you to do:

```
df.mutate(
    (pl.col("nrs")+1).alias("nrs+1"), 
    (pl.col("nrs+1")+1).alias("nrs+2"), 
    **{'nrs+3':pl.col('nrs+2')+1},
    nrs4=pl.col('nrs+3')+1
    )

shape: (5, 5)
┌──────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬──────┐
│ nrs  ┆ nrs+1 ┆ nrs+2 ┆ nrs+3 ┆ nrs4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 2     ┆ 3     ┆ 4     ┆ 5    │
│ 2    ┆ 3     ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 6    │
│ 3    ┆ 4     ┆ 5     ┆ 6     ┆ 7    │
│ null ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ null │
│ 5    ┆ 6     ┆ 7     ┆ 8     ┆ 9    │
└──────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴──────┘
```